# Form JSON string with all room occupancy details

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to build a json string programmatically. I need to form a JSON string in below format which contains the details of each room like number of adults, child, and child ages.

```
{"rooms":[{"numAdults":2,"numChildren":3,"childAges":[2,12]}, {"numAdults":2,"numChildren":3,"childAges":[10,7,6]}, {"numAdults":2,"numChildren":0,"childAges":[]}]}
```

I'm getting all these details from drop down list.
Could anyone help me with this? Thanks for your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm a beginner in programming world. It would be great if you could give me some hints rather than a direct answer.

Comment: The problem is that from your question there is no way to even roughly estimate what your situation is. Like this, there is just no meaningful way to answer your question other than providing a full solution. Giving hints would just be random shots that are unlikely to help you or anyone else. You got to at least try and come up with a solution and show it here. Don't worry if you attempt doesn't yield any success, that's fine. But then you'll have some basis that can be discussed and improved with the help of the community.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it with out any help :P

Answer (score -1):

You can build an object and then call `JSON.stringify(obj)` on your object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify